# Why is YHWH Elohim never punctuated to demonstrate apposition?

Tags: hebrew, names-of-god, tetragrammaton

This may be a silly question, but the name "LORD God" has always confused me as the underlying Hebrew is "YHWH God," which just sounds awkward to me. Wouldn't a more helpful way to translate the phrase *YHWH Elohim* be to clarify with punctuation that *Elohim* is in apposition to *YHWH*? I've never seen it done like this so maybe I'm missing something:

For example, I think Genesis 2:4 (בְּיֹ֗ום עֲשֹׂ֛ות יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהִ֖ים אֶ֥רֶץ וְשָׁמָֽיִם) is made more clear if the appositive relationship is explicit.

> When *YHWH (God)* created earth and sky...

Comment: Welcome to BHSX. This is not a silly question and thanks for your contribution.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Most believe that this is a fuller (more complete) title of "LORD God" just as "Sovereign Lord" and others are.

Comment: Punctuation comma or parenthesis is not required for essential attributes or names like JESUS Christ. It is better understood with YHWH God, rather than Lord God.

Answer (score 2):

Of note is the fact that only God is spoken of in the opening chapter of Genesis, and the first three verses of chapter 2. This establishes categorically that the God who created everything is the God of the Hebrew scriptures. The Hebrew letters that (in English) give YHWH (the tetragram) occurs 6,973 times in the sacred Hebrew scriptures. It has variously been translated into English as Jehovah, or Yahweh.

Yes, the two Hebrew letters that mean 'God' are *el*. Yes, the three Hebrew letters that mean God as an object of worship are *elah*.  And the five Hebrew letters that mean God/gods as objects of worship are *elohim*. Elohim is used 30 times up till 2:3, then from 2:4 we get 'the LORD God' in most English translations. Should this not read "YHWH (God)"? That is the question.

Well, ***Young's literal translation*** (1898 edition) may be of interest to you, in case you haven't seen it. From verse 1 to chapter 2 verse 3 he constantly renders *elohim* as 'God'. But from 2:4 he has 'Jehovah God'. And he consistently gives the tetragram as Jehovah (but not always with 'God' following the divine name). However, the bare letters 'YHWH' make no more sense than does 'LORD'. That is because the capitalisation of the Hebrew letters that read 'yahweh' read as 'adonai 'when meaning 'He (who) is', and adoni means Lord. Capitalising it when the Creator is meant deals nicely with that.

After all, pagan deities have always been called 'el' - and in their plurality, 'elohim'. To just render that as 'God' does not give sufficient distinction between the Creator and all the many false gods of the pagans. As the Hebrew for Lord is the adonai bound up with He (who) is, YHWH, the one and only Creator, then to say Jehovah God makes sense, or maybe Yahweh God if you prefer, but bear in mind that the scriptures do not always allow for both words together. When they do, they are appropriately put together, as in *Young's Literal Translation*.

Answer (score 1):

The question "[What Does YHWH Elohim Mean?](https://www.nas.org/blogs/article/ask_a_scholar_what_does_yhwh_elohim_mean)" was asked on the National Association of Scholars website.

In the response, Dr. Mark D. Futato breaks down the meaning behind the two words individually and together. In his conclusion, he explains that the two words together are in apposition.

> Second, the relationship between YHWH and Elohim in the combination YHWH Elohim is one of apposition, that is to say the second noun is placed immediately after the first noun to provide some sort of further definition or explanation. The significance of this can be seen in Genesis 1 and Genesis 2. In Genesis 1 only Elohim is used to refer to deity. This is no doubt because of the universal perspective of this creation story. In Genesis 2, on the other hand, deity is referred to as YHWH Elohim. These two accounts converge to affirm that YHWH (the God of Israel) and not any other ancient Near Eastern deity is Elohim (the universal God).
>
> So then, YHWH Elohim does not mean "Lord of Gods...the one of many," but means that YHWH, the personal God who rules over Israel, is at one and the same time the universal God who rules over all.

Please note that "LORD God" is not a name but a title. YHWH is commonly known as the tetragrammaton and the personal name of God. Many bible translations have removed God's personal name, Jehovah or Yahweh, and replaced it with LORD. Why? That is a separate question that can be asked.